# wpf ServiceAuthenticationManager request header content blank when OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I am building a WCF HTTP webservice hosted on IIS and authenticate requests using basic authentication.

*Everything works perfectly* until I add `IsOneWay=true` to my `OperationContract`, which seems to clear the header of the request made available to my custom `ServiceAuthenticationManager`.

The code for the authentication looks like:

```
public class MyUserAuthentication : ServiceAuthenticationManager
{
    public override ReadOnlyCollection<IAuthorizationPolicy> Authenticate(ReadOnlyCollection<IAuthorizationPolicy> authPolicy, Uri listenUri, ref Message message)
    {
        var requestProperties = (HttpRequestMessageProperty)message.Properties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name];
        string rawAuthHeader = requestProperties.Headers["Authorization"]; // here rawAuthHeader == null
        IPrincipal principal = CheckCredentials(rawAuthHeader);
        [...]
```

and the `ServiceContract`:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)] // Works if [OperationContract(IsOneWay=false)]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/MyOperation", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    void MyOperation(MyDataType data);
}
```

---

Is there any reason why `IsOneWay=true` is tampering with the request headers? If not, any idea of what could be causing the issue?